# Compiling the VoigtDistribution PDF

Tags: compile, special-functions, complex, distributions

According to [List of compilable functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1096), `Erf` and `Erfc` are compilable functions.

However, I want to make a compiled version of the `PDF` of a `VoigtDistribution` to use in a `NonlinearModelFit`, and it doesn't seem that the `Erfc` of a complex value will compile:

```
funcReal = 
 Compile[{{x, _Real}}, Erfc[x I], CompilationTarget -> "C", 
  RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]
funcComplex = 
 Compile[{{x, _Complex}}, Erfc[x I], CompilationTarget -> "C", 
  RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]

Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"];
CompilePrint[funcReal] (*same as funcComplex*)

    1 argument
    2 Real registers
    4 Complex registers
    Underflow checking off
    Overflow checking off
    Integer overflow checking off
    RuntimeAttributes -> {}

    R0 = A1
    C0 = 0. + 1. I
    R1 = 0.
    Result = C3

1   C1 = R0 + R1 I
2   C1 = C1 * C0
3   C2 = R0 + R1 I
4   C2 = C2 * C0
5   C3 = MainEvaluate[ Hold[Erfc][ C2]]
6   Return
```

Note the call to `MainEvaluate`:

```
Erfc[I] // N
funcReal[1]
funcComplex[1]

1. - 1.65043 I

1. - 1.65043 I

1. - 1.65043 I
```

All the functions work, but because of the `MainEvaluate`, they offer no performance benefit. How can I compile this function? Is this possible? Is there an alternative formula I could use?

Removing the `CompilationTarget` doesn't solve the problem either.

Comment: They compile for real values, but do not appear to compile for complex arguments.

Comment: Look at e.g. `Plot3D[Arg@Erf[x + I y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]`. This is not a function you would probably wish to try to find an alternative formula for, even approximately.

Comment: On the other hand, regarding the PDF of the Voigt distribution: http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0368-2048(94)02189-7

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://wolfram.com/xid/0bh19jsif7713e-epvv7q), we have a [pseudo-Voigt Distribution](http://dx.doi.org/10.1107/S0021889800010219) that might be used as an approximation. This might be useful as a basis for making a compilable function.

```
PseudoVoigtDistribution[δ_, σ_] := 
 Block[{g = (δ^5 + σ^5 + 2.69296 σ^4 δ + 2.42843 σ^3 δ^2 + 
        4.47163 σ^2 δ^3 + 0.07842 σ δ^4)^(1/5), η},
       η = δ/g;
       η = η*(1.36603 - 0.47719 η + 0.11116 η^2);
       MixtureDistribution[{1 - η, η}, {NormalDistribution[0, g], 
                           CauchyDistribution[0, g]}]
       ]
```

Answer (score 11):

Here is a compiled implementation of the Voigt profile function, based on an approximation derived by [Chiarella and Reichel](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-1968-0223068-4) and improved by [Abrarov, Quine and Jagpal](http://arxiv.org/abs/1208.2062):

```
voigt = With[{n = 24, τ = 12},
             With[{d = N[Range[n] π/τ], b = N[Exp[-(Range[n] π/τ)^2]],
                   s = N[PadRight[{}, n, {-1, 1}]],
                   sq = N[Sqrt[2]], sp = N[Sqrt[2 π]]},
                  Compile[{{δ, _Real}, {σ, _Real}, {x, _Real}},
                          Module[{z = (x + I δ)/(σ sq), e}, e = Exp[I τ z];
                                 Re[(I (1 - e)/(τ z) + (2 I z/τ)
                                    b.((e s - 1)/((d + z) (d - z))))]/(σ sp)],
                          RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}]]];
```

The compiled function performs remarkably well on my box:

```
vp = PDF[VoigtDistribution[1, 3/2]];
AbsoluteTiming[v1 = vp[N[Range[-7, 7, 1/50]]];]
   {3.70813, Null}

AbsoluteTiming[v2 = voigt[1, 3/2, Range[-7, 7, 1/50]];]
   {0.053813, Null}

Norm[v1 - v2, ∞]
   1.38778*10^-16
```

Further speed could probably be squeezed out by explicitly expanding out the complex arithmetic into its real and imaginary components, but the resulting code will look comparatively unwieldy.

Comment: You could consider submitting this to the new function repository: https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/ It would be a great addition!