# Convolve and fitting

Tags: fitting, convolution

I want to convolve two equation, then I want to find the parameters. But it doesn't give the answer and Takes too much time. What is the wrong with my code?

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[
   data, {Convolve[
     a*UnitStep[x - b]*c*Sqrt[x - b]*
       Divide[Pi*Divide[Sqrt[d], Sqrt[x - b]]*
         Exp[Pi*Divide[Sqrt[d], Sqrt[x - b]]], 
        Sinh[Pi*Divide[Sqrt[d], Sqrt[x - b]]]] + 
      a*d*Sum[Divide[4*Pi, n^3]*DiracDelta[x - b + d/n^2], {n, 1, 1}],
      VoigtDistribution, x, y], b < Min[data[[All, 1]]], 
    b < Min[data[[All, 1]]]}, {{a, 10}, {b, -1}, c, d}, x];
nlm["BestFitParameters"]
```

Comment: I noticed, that `VoigtDistribution` requieres 2 parameters but you provided none.

Comment: What does it mean, is it X and y?could you tell me how to use Voigt distribution function   correctly

Comment: How do I enter those parameters with my code? I have around 600 experimental data. Could you please make it correct?

Comment: You've asked 8 questions (with several of them appearing to be about the same dataset and model), few responses from you, and no accepting of any answers.  Please respond to the answers and/or comments to get this issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I neither know the context of your calculation nor do I know properties of the Voigt distribution so I cannt help you choose those:
According to the [reference](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VoigtDistribution.html) and the [wikipedia-article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voigt_profile) it should be `VoigtDistribution[sigma,delta]` where `sigma` is the standard-error of the underlying gauss distributionand delta is the $\gamma$ of the unerdlying Lorentz distribution.

As `VoigtDistribution[\sigma,\delta]` gives you a distribution you have to use

```
PDF[VoigtDistribution[sigma,delta],x]
```

Secondly you should test around if your expression within the NonlinearModel fit evaluates and trace the error piece by piece.

Comment: Should one find the built-in Voigt function to be too slow, [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/99347) might be of interest.

Comment: Thank you very much